# What is the maximum file path length we can have in share point online document libraries

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, limitations

We have a SharePoint online tenant, and i need to know what is the maximum length of the folders/sub-folders and file we can have, is there is any? for example can i add a file inside this path:-

*>>Main folder >> Sub folder1 >> ...sub folder100 >> Filename.txt* ?

Answer (score 4):

The maximum length is 400 encoded characters in the *URL*. There is no restriction on the number of folders/subfolders given it doesn't exceed this limit.

[Invalid file names and file types in OneDrive, OneDrive for Business, and SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/invalid-file-names-and-file-types-in-onedrive-onedrive-for-business-and-sharepoint-64883a5d-228e-48f5-b3d2-eb39e07630fa?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#filenamepathlengths)

Comment: thank for the reply, but i were reading this article https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/0a130c08-bce1-426b-b13a-06f206a73bf8/the-parametersleafname-argument-is-invalid?forum=SP2016 and it says that the maximum for any folder path is 128?

Comment: Even that is incorrect, in SharePoint Server 2016 the limit is 260 characters. SPO/SharePoint Server 2019 use the 400 character limit, per the official article.

Comment: Actually, the linked article says (at least now) that the maximum DECODED file path is 400 characters (with caveats about which part of the path are included). There is no mention of the length of encoded path length.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to google for the limit and find out that it is 400 decoded characters. But it's not clear what this means. So...

**A simple explanation:**

The highlighted part of the URL below, must be at most 400 characters. And by the way everything that looks like one character counts as one character.

> somecompany.sharepoint.com/Some%20Site/Some-Subsite/Some-Document-Library/Forms/AllItems.aspx?id=%2F`A folder/some subfolder/And some text with non Latin, non ASCII, ελληνικούς χαρακτήρες`&viewid=f821a73a-95c5-4ae3-b474-982c674b7dcb

**More details and technical information**

Note that if you copy paste the URL your browser may mangle it (URL encode it). Copy just this part and it will leave it untouched.

We count Unicode(decoded) characters (not ASCII characters after UTF-8 encoding, neither ASCII characters after URL encoding nor anything similar). I tested this assumption by first hitting the limit with ASCII characters and then changing some of them to Greek characters.

Finally, note that during my tests I actually reached 401 characters.